# Parallel programming problems

Tags: algorithm, math, parallel-processing

What are interesting problems to solve in parallel computing? I am thinking of well known problems that are not too complex but show linear improvement when using multiple processes. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You may want to consider this article, since it sounds like you're actually asking for a list of ["embarrassingly parallel" problems.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel)